# Summernote WYSIWYG editor not rendering data correctly with Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, summernote, laravel-5.8

I have a problem when I want to rendering data and Images from database, I'm using Summernote and Laravel, I will paste my Code of the controller and views, thanks in advance.

I get summer note show correctly with all his options, but when I try to add some things in my text like make it bold or something like that he did not work.

Controller:

```
public function createPost(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [

            'title' => 'required',

            'description' => 'required',

        ]);

        $title = $request->input('title');

        $description = $request->input('description');

        $writer = Auth::user()->id;

        $dom = new \DomDocument();

        $dom->loadHtml($description, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    

        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

        foreach($images as $k => $img){

            $data = $img->getAttribute('src');
            list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
            list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
            $data = base64_decode($data);
            $image_name= "/upload/" . time().$k.'.png';
            $path = public_path() . $image_name;
            file_put_contents($path, $data);
            $img->removeAttribute('src');
            $img->setAttribute('src', $image_name);

        }

        $description = $dom->saveHTML();

        $post = new Post;
        $post->title= $title;
        $post->description = $description;
        $post->writer = $writer;
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Post has been successfully added!'); 
}
```

Add view:

```
        @if(Auth::check())
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="post" action="{{ route('post.form') }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_title" name="title"
                           aria-describedby="title" placeholder="Enter title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
        @endif
```

Call of the summernote:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content').summernote({
            height:300,
        });

    });
</script>
```

Example of the result, title plus content : 
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

You should use `{!! $description !!}` to print as html.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the output in the browser, maybe the summernote plugin is not called properly,

In head tag, check the javascript plugin, and the css as well. Put them is proper order.

Comment: Hello bro, thank you for your reply I think i call the them very well:
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.js"></script>

Comment: can you inspect in your browser? and see is there any error or not? and your test output is in the view while you show the value in the view or while you are using the plugin? if its in the view while you want to show the result, use {!! $description !!}

Comment: Thank you, i called the variable like that {!! $post->description !!} and its work, thank you again